# Multiple reference to same object

Tags: java

```
Point origin = new Point(23,23);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(origin);

        1) System.out.println(origin.getX()+" "+origin.getY());
        2) System.out.println(rect.getX()+" "+rect.getY());

        System.out.println("----------------------");

        origin.setLocation(90, 90);

        3) System.out.println(origin.getX()+" "+origin.getY());
        4) System.out.println(rect.getX()+" "+rect.getY());
```

Can someone explain why the 4th statement does not print 90,90? 
Rather 4th line prints 23,23. When the point object is changed then it should have changed the rectangle object also but the it does not changes.

I amreferring the below URL which says object can have multiple reference. Why is rectangle not changed when it also refers to the same object

P.S. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Because those are _not_ multiple references to the same object.

Comment: Simple trick: in Java, if there is a `new ` at the front, it's creating a new object for sure.

Comment: Show us the `Rectangle` constructor. I am pretty sure it makes a copy rather than just referencing the origin object.

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you included what `Point` and `Rectangle` classes the ones in your code are exactly (Full qualified name with package). I'm guessing those are the `java.awt` classes. In if you look at the code of the constructor you used of `java.awt.Rectangle` you would see that the constructor copies the x/y values from the `Point` supplied, but does not save a reference to the Point itself.

Comment: I realized my mistake....Thank you everyone. You people are very quick...thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your premise is wrong. Those are neither two references to the same object (one is a `Point`, the other a `Rectangle`), nor does the `Rectangle` hold a reference to the `Point`.

This is the code of the constructor (assuming `java.awt.Rectangle`):

```
public Rectangle(Point p) {
    this(p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
}
```

I.e., the rectangle unpacks the coordinates from the points, and keeps no other reference to the original point, so when the point is changed, the rectangle does not change.

---

Having said that, the [`Rectangle` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java) that is used in the tutorial you linked to in your question *does* hold a reference to the `Point` and thus *would* update its origin position if the point is changed. Thus, I'd guess that you missed that part and used the wrong (builtin) `Rectangle` class when following the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Because those are not reference to the same object, as you wrote

`Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(origin);`

You created a new `Rectangle` from a `Point` object, hence you have 2 object in your runtime execution: 1 Rectangle and 1 Point.

You can think as the `new` keyword as a simple copy-paste on your data from an object to another, but no deep linking is done (unless you force it in implementation)

Comment: I think the question is *"why doesn't the `Rectangle` retain a reference to the `Point`?"*

Comment: @kaya3 I agree that is probably why OP is confused, but I think both answers address valid points where OP _could_ have gotten confused.

Comment: I mean, I don't think the OP believes that the `Rectangle` and the `Point` are the same object.

Comment: @kaya3 Did you read the title?  It doesn't hurt to address multiple points in different answers.

Comment: Yes, I think you are supposed to interpret *"multiple references to the same object"* as meaning *"multiple references to the same `Point` object"* - i.e. one from the main method, one from the `Rectangle` object.

Comment: @kaya3 Which is my point, I agree that is likely how it should be interpreted, but since it is not completely clear having different answers address different interpretations is acceptable in my opinion.  I don't even disagree with you, I just think his answer is fine as well.

Comment: I didn't say the answer hurts or is unacceptable. I just think it's missing the more likely reason that someone might be confused about this behaviour.

Comment: @kaya3 I think you are confused, I am not the person that wrote either answer, I am a third party.

Comment: My mistake, the small font size in comments isn't the best for me. Yes, I don't think we disagree.